# Use mechanize to select correct submit button

Tags: python, html, mechanize

I'm using mechanize in my Python script to access web page sources. One of the pages I want to access uses two buttons to ask if I am 21 or not. I'm very new to python, and after searching all day, I can't figure out how to select the correct button in the same form because they have the same name. Printing the forms yields:

```
<SubmitButtonControl(over21=no) (readonly)>
<SubmitButtonControl(over21=yes) (readonly)>>
```

The HTML for the buttons, which are in the same form:

```
<button class="c-btn c-btn-primary" type="submit" name="over21"value="no">no thank you</button>
<button class="c-btn c-btn-primary" type="submit" name="over21"value="yes">continue</button>
```

What I've tried:

```
thisone = br.select_form(name='over21=yes')
br.submit(thisone)
```

Which yields error:

```
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 524,in select_form
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'over21=yes'
```

I've also tried

```
br.submit(nr=1)
```

which was suggested by another post, but I believe that is selecting a whole different form for me.
Any advice welcome! And yes, I am over 21! Thanks,